# EF Core 2.2 scaffold existing database - is there a way to filter out tables from the model

Tags: entity-framework-core, dotnet-cli, ef-core-2.2

I know there is a -Tables parameter to include only those in a list, but is there a way instead to have a filter of some sort to exclude those tables from the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF Core Power Tools saves your selection

Comment: ErikEJ - I was watching your video yesterday about EF power tools.  I've been using the reverse poco generator on another project with EF 6.x and it works awesome.